# How to style Ajax Calendar inside a gridview

Tags: asp.net, css

When the calendar pops up, it appears behind the textbox of the successive row,and so hiding a few dates. How can I fix this.

```
<asp:gridview>
  <asp:Templatefield>
    <itemtemplate>
      <div style="position:relative">
        <asp:textbox id="txtDate"/>
        <asp:calendarextender   popupposition="bottomright" 
         Targetcontrolid="txtDate"/>
      </div>
    </itemtemplate>
  </asp:Templatefield>
</asp:gridview>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set for your "asp:calendarextender" this style

```
z-index:6500;
```

Comment: I had to do it this way - `.ajax__calendar_container{z-index:6500 !important;}`. Thank you @saeed.